# Is there a way to automatically reply/react to a Discord bot's message (Mudae)?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a program that responds or reacts to a Discord bot's message if the message contains my desired sentence or value.

The bot I have in mind is Mudae, an anime character gacha generator. The program should type " message.react(":heart:")" or click on the default claim reaction if my desired character does appear

Comment: This is possible. Just check the parameters you're looking for - the bot (message.author.id) and the desired value (message.content).

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use:

- [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) events to get messages
- [`Member.bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member%20bot#discord.Member.bot) or [`Member.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member%20id#discord.Member.id)
- [`Message.add_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20add#discord.Message.add_reaction) to add reactions to messages
- [`Messageable.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=send#discord.abc.Messageable.send) to respond to a message

Here's a simple example:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot: #Check if author is not a bot
        return
    if ':heart:' in message.content:
        message.add_reaction('❤️')
    elif 'hello' in message.content:
        message.channel.send(f'Hi {message.author.mention} :)')

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

PS: `on_message` events override commands so you need `await bot.process_commands(message)` in order to be able to use commands along side with `on_message` events.